# receive gstreamer UDP packets in vmware

Tags: vmware, gstreamer

I've installed Fedora 19 as a guest OS in VMware 10.0.1, which is running in a
Win7 host. I send live video from another computer with UDP to host using GStreamer and I'm trying to redirect its packets to guest machine via Simple UDP proxy/pipe (sudppipe).

Using "tcpdump" command on guest machine I'm sure that the packets are received. however, the following GStreamer pipeline dump nothing on guest!?!

```
[elin@localhost ~]$ gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc uri=udp://192.168.0.103:11234 ! fakesink dump=1
```

Does anyone know what's the problem?

**Additional information:**

IPs:

- **Host (Win7):** 192.168.0.100:50000
- **Guest (Fedora19):** 192.168.0.103:11234
- **VMnet (NAT):** 192.168.0.102

sudppipe command on win7:

```
sudppipe -b 192.168.0.100 192.168.0.103 11234 50000
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ``sudppipe``util. It is really useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem. The problem was due to Linux firewall setting. After disabling the firewall (see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-flush-all-rules.html)), I am able to receive gstreamer UDP packets in vmware.